# Changing Button initial currentState based on connection status

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I would like my Button to have it's currentState initialized with my own defined state. I am monitoring the internet connection and the initial currentstate of my Button will depend on the connection status. I think the initial state is set on the SkinnableComponent commitProperties function:

```
override protected function commitProperties():void
{
    super.commitProperties();

    if (skinChanged)
    {
        skinChanged = false;
        validateSkinChange();
    }

    if (skinStateIsDirty)
    {
        // This component must first be updated to the pending state as the
        // skin inherits styles from this component.
        var pendingState:String = getCurrentSkinState();
        stateChanged(skin.currentState, pendingState, false);
        skin.currentState = pendingState;
        skinStateIsDirty = false;
    }...
```

So I have my button skin and depending on the connection status I want to change the icon. I overwrite the function initializationComplete of my skin class so that when the connection status change, my currentState also changes.

```
        override protected function initializationComplete():void
        {
            useChromeColor = true;
            BindingUtils.bindSetter(onConnectionChange,ServiceMonitor.getInstance(),'connectionStatus');
            super.initializationComplete();
        }  

        protected function onConnectionChange(value:Object):void
        {
            if(ServiceMonitor.getInstance().connectionStatus == 'Service.available')
                currentState = 'downOnline';
            else if(ServiceMonitor.getInstance().connectionStatus != 'Service.available')
                currentState = 'downOffline';
        }
```

This works fine except on the initialization of the component the initial state overwrites my own. I solved this by overwriting the commitProperties function and by calling the function onConnectionChange after the skin calls the function commitProperties. Here is my overwritten commitProperties function of my ButtonSkin:

```
                    override protected function commitProperties():void
        {
            super.commitProperties();
            onConnectionChange(null);
        }
```

Since I do not know how much processing changing the currentState causes, I am afraid that by calling to many times the function onConnectionChange and therefore changing the currentState several times I am affecting negatively the performance. The thing is the function onConnectionChange itself causes the commitProperties to be called. So there is extra processing already there. Question is how much and isn't there a better approach for this. Thank you very much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a couple of things to note:

1. You are changing state on what effectively is a 'leaf' display object. Flex/Flash and essentially any other design platform is based on a hierarchy - so unless you're changing state / styles on either root application itself or a large trunk of the application - any performance degradation on this alone is going to be minuscule.
2. You can validate this for yourself in the SDK, the majority of bindable expressions generally disregard a change of the same state - to prevent the very issue you are concerned about.

Is there a better way? Maybe, maybe not. It ultimately depends on what exactly you want / how much needs to change.

If the only thing you are attempting to change is the icon, this is the approach I take:

```
<s:ToggleButton id="pendingBtn" width="22" height="22" toolTip="View Pending" 
                icon="{AssetManager.pending_closed}" 
                icon.PendingTransactions="{AssetManager.pending_open}"
                selected.PendingTransactions="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. In which phase of the components' initialization would you say it's more appropriate to change the currentState without having it being overwritten?

Comment: You're in the right area - the commitProperties cycle - basically before measurement but after createChildren.

Styles on the other hand, are better off being applied in a preinitialize event and/or setStyle - right after create children generally because of binding of inherited proto chains.